# Find and replace in shell script (special characters)

Tags: shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting:

I have following:

```
old=/dev/sda
new=/dev/sda5
```

Given these variables, I need to extract `5` from "new" string.

How should I go about it? `sed`? `awk`?

Tried using:

```
partitionno=$(echo $new | sed 's/$old//g')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the correct result with the least change to your command, try:

```
partitionno=$(echo "$new" | sed "s|$old||g")
```

There are two key points here:

1. Shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes.  So `'$old'` remains as the original four characters: `$`, `o`, `l`, and `d`.  For the shell variables to be expanded, use double quotes.
2. `sed "s/$old//g"` still won't work because there are too many slashes.  A substitute command uses three slashes.  After the shell expands `$old`, there are five slashes.  The solution is to use a different delimiter for the substitute command.  I chose `|` above because `|` is not likely to be in a file name.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ old=/dev/sda
$ new=/dev/sda5
$ echo "${new#$old}"
5
```

> ${parameter#word}
>
> ${parameter##word}
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion (see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.